# Green function of a fourth order ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, greens-function

please what is the method to find the Green function associated to the following fourth order ode 
$$
\begin{cases}
u^{(4)}(t)+\beta\, u^{(2)}(t)-\alpha\,u(t) =0,\,\, t\in[0,1]\\
u(0)=u(1)=u''(0)=u''(1)=0
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The Green function $G(t,s)$ solves for fixed $s$ the system for $u(t)=G(t,s)$
\begin{cases}
u^{(4)}(t)+\beta\, u^{(2)}(t)-\alpha\,u(t) =\delta(t-s),\,\, t\in[0,1]\\
u(0)=u(1)=u''(0)=u''(1)=0
\end{cases}
so that $u(t)=\int_0^1G(t,s)f(s)ds$ is the general solution if the right side is $f(t)$.
This means that 
$$
G(t,s)=\begin{cases}
u_L(t),&t<s,\\u_R(t),&t\ge s,
\end{cases}
$$
where

- $u_L, u_R$ are solutions of the homogeneous equation,
- $u_L$ satisfies the left boundary conditions,
- $u_R$ the right boundary conditions,
- $u_L(s)=u_R(s)$, $u_L'(s)=u_R'(s)$, $u_L''(s)=u_R''(s)$ and
- $u_L'''(s)+1=u_R'''(s)$ so that the 4th derivative produces the delta term.

Comment: This methods work always ? even in $u^{(4)}(t)+\beta u^{(2)}(t)+\gamma u'(t)-\alpha u(t)$ ?

Comment: what it means satisfy the left\right boundary condition ??

Comment: Yes, this "works" because the Dirac delta acts as unit for the convolution product. The left function satisfies the left boundary conditions, that is, those at $t=0$, $u_L(0)=u_L''(0)=0$ and similarly for the right at $t=1$.

Comment: here we have fourth solutions so why just two u_L and u_R?

Comment: Please @Lutzl I found the solutions for the homogeneous equations how to do to obtain the solution with $ \delta(t-s)$ ? thank you